# Derivation of posterior distribution of Kalman filter

Tags: bayesian, kalman-filter

I am following this article on [Understanding the Kalman filter](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Understanding-the-Kalman-Filter-Meinhold-Singpurwalla/55a5dcf5a28ce74480f4ebf09e8030e36dabe7aa) by Meinhold,  and I can understand all the derivation up until equation (4.4). However, I cannot understand how they arrive at the posterior estimates of $\theta_t$ conditioned on the error term and data $Y_{t-1}$. How is this derived?

Comment: As the authors state, you simply plug (4.3) into (4.2).  This is purely a matter of algebraic substitution -- almost no simplification has occurred (apart from omitting a "$-0$" from the mean).